How do I fix this Reg ex so that it matches hyphenated words where the final segment ends in a consonant other than the letter m
I want to match all cases where a hyphenated string (which could be made up of one or multiple hyphenated segments) ends in a consonant that is not the letter m.
In other words, it needs to match strings such as: 'crack-l', 'crac-ken', 'cr-ca-cr-cr' etc. but not 'crack' (not hyphenated), 'br-oom' (ends in m), br -oo (last segment ends in vowel) or cr-ca-cr-ca (last segment ends in vowel).
It is mostly successful except for cases where there is more than one hyphen, then it will return part of the string such as 'cr-ca-cr' instead of the whole string which should be 'cr-ca-cr-ca'.
Here is the code I have tried with example data:
import re
dummy_data = """ 
broom  
br-oom
br-oo
crack
crack-l
crac-ken
crack-ed
cr-ca-cr-ca
cr-ca-cr-cr
cr-ca-cr-cr-cr
"""
pattern = r'\b(?:\w+-)+\w*[bcdfghjklnpqrstvwxyz](?<!m)\b'
final_consonant_hyphenated = [
    m.group(0)
    for m in re.finditer(pattern, dummy_data, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
]
print(final_consonant_hyphenated)`

expected output:
['crack-l', 'crac-ken', 'crack-ed', 'cr-ca-cr-cr', 'cr-ca-cr-cr-cr']

current output:
 ['crack-l', 'crac-ken', 'crack-ed', **'cr-ca-cr'**, 'cr-ca-cr-cr', 'cr-ca-cr-cr-cr']

(bold string is an incorrect match as it's part of the cr-ca-cr-ca string where the final segment ends in a vowel not a consonant).

This part is always true (?<!m) as there is no m to match in the preceding character class

You could add a negative lookahead to prevent having a hyphen after and also an idea to shorten [bcdfghjklnpqrstvwxyz](?<!m) to [a-z](?<![aeioum]).
Update: Further as @Thefourthbird mentioned in the comments, as well putting the lookbehind after the word-boundary \b will result in better performance (fewer steps).
\b(?:\w+-)+\w*[a-z]\b(?<![aeioum])(?!-)

See this demo at regex101 or even \b(?:\w+-)+\w+\b(?<![aeioum\d_])(?!-) (without the [a-z], using \w+ instead of \w* and also disallowing digits and underscore from \w in the lookbehind). With a possessive quantifier (using PyPI) further reduced: \b(?:\w+-)+\w++(?<![aeioum\d_])(?!-)

Of course! I'll update the answer accordingly... good improvement  @Thefourthbird.

Would it matter that this could be part of a larger substring? Say '$%#-blah-blah'.

Thank you all! @JvdV sorry please explain your comment more?

@PaigeCox, I don't want to hijack this answer for that too much, but since the ending negative lookahead asserts that the substring shouldn't be part of a larger substring containing more hypened parts I thought maybe you want to assert the same thing at the start.

@JvdV This doesn't matter, does it? It's just about the ending not the beginning... so far. :D

Sorry I'm a reg ex novice here, but yes bobblebubble's answer I think sums it up - only interested in the end of the hyphenated string @JvdV

@bobblebubble, it depends. Hence my example substring. Would OP want to match the last part of that substring ('blah-blah') regardless, or does the fact that it's part of a larger substring containing unwanted characters make for a false positive. Either way, maybe I'm getting into it too much :)

@JvdV Certainly when thinking further! I only sticked to the current scenario with my answer.

@PaigeCox thanks for the response, let me introduce you to a few sample-strings and do please let me know if they should be matched: !@#-ab, !@#-ab-ab, !@#-$%^b. Again, you have been clear it's about the end of a delimited string, but just so that you are aware of what you are matching can be part of larger substrings.

@JvdV thanks for checking! But I don't think these types of strings would occur in my data.

Note that, starting with Python 3.11, atomic groups and possessive quantifiers are available in the re module.
